# Get 5 least busy staff members

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm developing an online competition that allows judges to vote on entrants. When the current round of the competition ends, it is closed and a bunch of things are done to set up the next round.

The current system format, say everyone who has been voted into the next round is to be judged by all competition judges. I do this with the following code in a stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO recEntrantStatus (entrantId, roundId, judgeId, notified, voted, enterNextRound)
    SELECT r.entrantId, (@input + 1), j.judgeId /*Now getting tblJudges Id*/, 0, 0, 0
    FROM recEntrantStatus r
        -- Get all of the judges
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Id AS judgeId FROM recMembers
                     WHERE Privilege >= 2) AS j
        WHERE r.roundId = @input
          AND r.voted = 1
          AND r.enterNextround = 1
```

You'll see that this get the entrants details from recEntrantStatus, and the judges data from recMembers. So essentially finds everyone who voted into round 2 and then creates a record for every judge for that entrant. So in round 2 every judge judges every entrant.

However, the competition has changed and I need to update the Stored Procedure to allocate each contestant to just five judges rather than all judges. Additionally, all the contestants should be allocated evenly to each judge.

Previously I've used the following code:

```
SELECT TOP(5) MEM.Id, ISNULL(ES.EntrantCount, 0)
FROM recMembers MEM
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT judgeid, COUNT(judgeid) 'EntrantCount'
        FROM recEntrantStatus
        WHERE roundId = 1
        GROUP BY judgeid
        ) ES ON MEM.Id = ES.judgeid
WHERE MEM.Privilege = 2
ORDER BY EntrantCount
```

This check all the records in recEntrantStatus, groups them by the judgeId's and then counts them up. The 5 judges with the least number of contestants/records allocated to them get returned.

However, I've tried using a combination of the two -as follows- but this fails to run or save:

```
INSERT INTO recEntrantStatus (entrantId, roundId, judgeId, notified, voted, enterNextRound)
    SELECT r.entrantId, (@input + 1), j.judgeId /*Now getting tblJudges Id*/, 0, 0, 0
    FROM recEntrantStatus r
    -- Get all of the judges
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP(5) MEM.Id, ISNULL(ES.EntrantCount, 0)
                    FROM recMembers MEM
                    LEFT JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT judgeid, COUNT(judgeid) 'EntrantCount'
                        FROM recEntrantStatus
                        WHERE roundId = 1
                        GROUP BY judgeid
                    ) ES ON MEM.Id = ES.judgeid
                    WHERE MEM.Privilege = 2
                    ORDER BY EntrantCount ) AS j
    WHERE r.roundId = @input
      AND r.voted = 1
      AND r.enterNextround = 1
```

The errors I get are:

> No column name was specified for column 2 of 'j'.

and

> Invalid column name 'judgeId'.

Comment: It looks like column 2 of `j` is your `ISNULL(ES.EntrantCount, 0)`, so giving that column a name might fix issue #1.

Comment: Good point @AdamV Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues: as Adam V pointed out in the comments, you didn't name one of the two fields in the `j` query. In addition, you have the wrong field name `judgeID` - what you need to pull is just `Id`.

```
INSERT INTO recEntrantStatus (entrantId, roundId, judgeId, notified, voted, enterNextRound)
    SELECT 
        r.entrantId, 
        (@input + 1), 
        j.Id /*Now getting tblJudges Id*/,  -- fixed name
        0, 
        0, 
        0
    FROM recEntrantStatus r
    -- Get all of the judges
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP(5) MEM.Id, ISNULL(ES.EntrantCount, 0) EntrantCount
                    FROM recMembers MEM
                    LEFT JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT judgeid, COUNT(judgeid) AS 'EntrantCount' -- name this
                        FROM recEntrantStatus
                        WHERE roundId = 1
                        GROUP BY judgeid
                    ) ES ON MEM.Id = ES.judgeid
                    WHERE MEM.Privilege = 2
                    ORDER BY EntrantCount ) AS j
    WHERE r.roundId = @input
      AND r.voted = 1
      AND r.enterNextround = 1
```

Comment: I need the id of the judge though... This is found in the table 'recMembers' and should be returned by the 'SELECT judgeid, COUNT(judgeid) AS 'EntrantCount' -- name this
                        FROM recEntrantStatus
                        WHERE roundId = 1
                        GROUP BY judgeid' statement.

Comment: Yet what you're actually pulling in the `SELECT TOP(5)` is the `MEM.Id` field, NOT the `JudgeID` field.  If you want to change that, you need to add JudgeID to the `SELECT TOP(5)`.  Since you are using `MEM.Id = ES.judgeID` in your JOIN condition, I assumed that they were interchangeable.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if I needed to call MEM.Id directly rather than J.Id but it seems you were correct. However, I've just run the query and it actually returns every record for each of the identified 5 judges. All I need is to pull 1 record so that I can grab the judge id's. Any suggestions as to how to remedy this?

Comment: Yes - define the relationship between `recEntrantStatus` and your `recMembers` table.  `CROSS JOIN` will return a Cartesian product of every record in `recEntrantStatus` multiplied by the five judges in `j`.

Comment: Hold on. I may be confusing myself and you here. Let me check where my head is ;-)

Comment: it appears its doing exactly what it is supposed to do. I forgot we were creating a row for every entrant : judge combination. Thanks for the help, that looks perfect now.

Comment: On further testing I realised this isn't quite right. For every record created it uses the same 5 judges / staff. What I actually need is for the 5 judges / staff members to be calculated and inserted for every new record created. Any suggestions?

Comment: Same as before - define some kind of relationship between the `recEntrantStatus` and your `recMembers` table.   _How do you want to assign judges to entrants?_ Based on your question, are you trying to assign them randomly based on how many entrants the judge has???

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do. The idea is to ensure that all judges have a similar number of entrants associated with them.

Comment: I've created a new question for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293629/detect-top-5-from-b-for-each-record-in-a