# Detect TOP 5 from B for each record in A

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm creating an online competition where entrants are allocated to a judge, and this judge decides if they proceed to the next round.

Once the first round closes, the second round is prepared in the database as follows:

Each contestant/entrant who is put through to round 2 is allocated to 5 judges. These judges should be allocated based on how many contestants are already allocated to them. In other words, each judge should have a similar number of people to judge in round two.

At present I have the following SQL statement in a stored procedure, which is called 1 time when the competition is moved to round 2:

```
INSERT INTO recEntrantStatus (entrantId, roundId, judgeId, notified, voted, enterNextRound)
SELECT 
    r.entrantId, 
    (@input + 1), 
    j.Id /*Now getting tblJudges Id*/,  -- fixed name
    0, 
    0, 
    0
FROM recEntrantStatus r
-- Get all of the judges
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP(5) MEM.Id, ISNULL(ES.EntrantCount, 0) EntrantCount
                FROM recMembers MEM
                LEFT JOIN
                (
                    SELECT judgeid, COUNT(judgeid) AS 'EntrantCount' -- name this
                    FROM recEntrantStatus
                    WHERE roundId = 1
                    GROUP BY judgeid
                ) ES ON MEM.Id = ES.judgeid
                WHERE MEM.Privilege = 2
                ORDER BY EntrantCount ) AS j
WHERE r.roundId = @input
  AND r.voted = 1
  AND r.enterNextround = 1
```

However, this only calculates the 5 judges on the one occasion and allocates these same 5 judges to every contestant. What I actually need however is for the 5 judges to be recalculated for every contestant moved into round 2.

### Extra clarification

So, the aim is to calculate how many records each judge has for the current round(roundId), then calculate/select the 5 judges with the fewest records. Then it should create 5 new records in the 'recEntrantStatus' table for the entrantId, with each record being the same except for the 'judgeId' column which will contain the relevant idea of one of the 5 judges. With five records in total, that means each contestant/entrant will have a record for each of 5 judges for the current round.

Then the process will be repeated for the next identified entrant/contestant(r.entrantId). Since we just added 5 new records, the 5 judges with the least number of contestants/records will have changed. So we determine who these are before creating a new row in the db for each of these 5 judges/ the contestant.

### SQL Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/426d5

Comment: I would need to see sample data, current results and desired results to be able to help.   Or a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Your SQL Fiddle doesn't contain any sample data. Also, after being given said sample data, we would need to know what the results should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is effectively a calculation based on an ongoing changing dataset its would not to me seem to be a set based operation..

As much as I'm loathe to recommend cursors I feel that this is probably the correct approach here.

Cursor each row from recEntrantStatus that needs moving up a round and perform the insert based on that row in turn.

### Edit

```
declare @entrant bigint

DECLARE entrant_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT entrantID
FROM  recEntrantStatus r
WHERE r.roundId = @input
AND r.voted = 1
AND r.enterNextround = 1

OPEN entrant_cursor



FETCH NEXT FROM entrant_cursor 
INTO @entrant

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO recEntrantStatus (entrantId, roundId, judgeId, notified, voted, enterNextRound)
SELECT 
    r.entrantId, 
  (@input + 1), 
j.Id /*Now getting tblJudges Id*/,  -- fixed name
0, 
0, 
0
FROM recEntrantStatus r
-- Get all of the judges
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP(5) MEM.Id, ISNULL(ES.EntrantCount, 0) EntrantCount
            FROM recMembers MEM
            LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT judgeid, COUNT(judgeid) AS 'EntrantCount' -- name this
                FROM recEntrantStatus
                WHERE roundId = 1
                GROUP BY judgeid
            ) ES ON MEM.Id = ES.judgeid
            WHERE MEM.Privilege = 2
            ORDER BY EntrantCount ) AS j
WHERE r.roundId = @input
AND r.voted = 1
AND r.enterNextround = 1
and r.entrantID = @entrant

FETCH NEXT FROM entrant_cursor 
INTO @entrant

END 
CLOSE entrant_cursor;
DEALLOCATE entrant_cursor;
```

MS Link for cursors: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180169.aspx

### Edit 2

There was a slight mistake in your original SQL change the line from my solution:

```
 ORDER BY EntrantCount ) AS j
```

to

```
 ORDER BY ISNULL(ES.EntrantCount, 0) ) AS j
```

The reason for this is you were ordering by the underlying EntrantCount not the one where you changed nulls to 0.

Comment: Sorry, SQL isn't really my greatest skillset. Could you elaborate a little? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately that still allocates the same set of 5 judges for each loop. I need to recalculate it every time. So that every insert has the 5 judges with the least records associated with them. Perhaps you could walk me through your answer a little, and I can hopefully work it out from there? P.s. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Hi Phill, that should do each row individually, but I might have made a typo or two in there... in this case I am using the cursor to queue up the entrants then performing the insert per entrant

Comment: Going to look at putting  some dummy data into your sql fiddle when I have a break here and will check what Ive done by hand

Comment: Good ole Microsoft. That link shows a really simple example and then a much more complex one but without explanation. ;-)

Comment: Altered my earlier answer ... think it was just that slight mistake in there ... very common easy to make one too. Basically SQL does exactly what you tell it based on the data in your statement, it didn't know you wanted to order by the isnulled entrantcount so used the original, and nulls come after whole numbers in terms of ordering as they have no known value

Comment: That still does the same. I think there may be an issue with my original sql since it doesn't appear to be taking into account any judges which do not have any contestants attributed to them in the recEntrantStatus table. I think I should probably go away and deconstruct my SQL first then open a new question when I have the relevant bits or the query/queries. Thanks for the help its really appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98097/discussion-between-andrew-sexton-and-phill-healey).